# asyncio run multiple tasks while preserving order and handling errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

my function `run_tasks(all_tasks, window_size)` that takes a generator of [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) tasks and returns their value while:

1. run each ***window*** (of size `window_size`) from the `all_tasks` concurrently
2. preserve the order of returned results (`all_tasks[i]` result is `results[i]`)
3. handle exceptions for each run

My current implementation:

```
import asyncio
from itertools import islice


# run all tasks and return their results in the same order
# window is the max number of tasks that will run in parallel
def run_tasks(all_tasks, window_size=4):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    while True:
        window_tasks = list(islice(all_tasks, window_size))
        if not window_tasks:
            break

        futures = asyncio.wait(window_tasks, loop=loop)
        finished, unfinished = loop.run_until_complete(futures)

        # sort finished tasks by their launch order.
        # removing this line makes returned tasks unordered
        finished = sorted(finished, key=lambda f: window_tasks.index(f._coro))

        for finished_task in finished:
            try:
                yield finished_task.result()
            except Exception as e:
                yield repr(e)

# Example Usage:

# a coroutine that sometime raises exception
async def sleepy(i):
    print(f'{i} started')
    await asyncio.sleep(10 - i)
    print(f'{i} finished')
    if i == 5:
        raise ValueError('5 is the worst')
    return i

# a generator of tasks
all_tasks = (sleepy(i) for i in range(10))

for result in list(run_tasks(all_tasks)):
    print(result)
```

## The Problem

The problem with my implementation is that I cannot find a way to sort the tasks in without accessing `f._coro` which is internal property of `asyncio.Task` object.

```
# removing this line makes returned tasks unordered
finished = sorted(finished, key=lambda f: window_tasks.index(f._coro))
```

I can use `asyncio.gather(*tasks)` but this will not handle errors.

I am open to suggestions on how to implement this three properties for `run_tasks()` without access to `f._coro`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asyncio.gather` [can](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) return you errors if you specify it's keyword param `return_exceptions`. To distinguish real exceptions from exception objects return as result of coroutine, you can wrap your `window_tasks` with tasks using `ensure_future`:

```
futures = [asyncio.ensure_future(t, loop=loop) for t in window_tasks]
gathered =  asyncio.gather(*futures, loop=loop, return_exceptions=True)
loop.run_until_complete(gathered)

for fut in futures:
    try:
        yield fut.result()
    except Exception as e:
        yield repr(e)
```

Comment: thanks, I really noticed the `return_exceptions` param but you cannot distinguish exceptions returned by it

Comment: `but you cannot distinguish exceptions returned by it` - you can. Just try code I posted. We need `return_exceptions` only not to raise exception by `asyncio.gather`. But we check not `gathered` results, we check results of `futures` we created. They will return normal coroutine result on `fut.result()` call and raise exception if exception raised in coroutine.

Comment: yes its correct, I tested it and it works. I just noted that i tried using return_exceptions and try looking at the result, but this as you noted might cause issues when the return value is of type exception. the key was to look at the future and not the result of the `loop.run_until_complete`